Need Dropdown Control with Duplicate Results in Looker Studio
I have created a table with names of companies in Column A and Boolean values under different columns for Rising Sales, Rising Profit and Rising Margins (in Column B, C and D respectively). Looker Studio allows me to create a dropdown control for choosing companies with either Rising Sales or Rising Profit or Rising Margins. However, some companies will be satisfying more than one Boolean also.
How do I create a dropdown control with options for Rising Sales, Rising Profit and Rising Margin, such that companies which satisfy more than one Boolean are shown in all the options. For example, if Company A satisfies Rising Sales as well as Rising Profit Booleans, it should appear in both the options and not just one.
I created a custom filter using CASE function, but it keeps the company in the first option which meet the criteria. So, Company A above (which has Rising Sales and Rising Profit) is appearing in Rising Sales only. If I choose Rising Profit, Company A doesn't appear there.
CASE
WHEN Rising Sales then "Rising Sales"
WHEN Rising Profit then "Rising Profit"
WHEN Rising Margin then "Rising Margin"
else "None"
END

You may see the report here: Sample Report for Dropdown Issue
